# How to group array obj by?

Tags: javascript

I'm new to grouping array obj. I tried the following and I believe I'm getting there but I'm missing something and I don't understand where:

Doing:

```
const result = data.map(function(item) {
  const ditem = dictionary.find(d => d.state == item.state);
  if(ditem) {
    return {
      ...item,
      "lat": ditem.lat ,
      "long": ditem.long
    }
  }
  return item;
});
console.log(result);

const formatted = result.map(area => {
  return {
    "state": area["state"],
    "lat": area["lat"],
    "long": area["long"],
    "datasets": Object.keys(area)
    .map(date => ({ date: area[date], negative: area[date]}))
  };
});
```

Giving me:

```
[
  {
    "state": "AK",
    "lat": "9875.33.00",
    "long": "-8371.42.00",
    "datasets": [
      {
        "date": 20200421,
        "negative": 20200421
      },
      {
        "date": "AK",
        "negative": "AK"
      },
      {
        "date": 329,
        "negative": 329
      },
      {
        "date": 10790,
        "negative": 10790...
```

Expecting example:

```
0:
  State: "AK", 
  Lat: 45.0732745
  Long: 7.680687483
  0: date: "2/24/20"
     positive: 329
     negative: 10790
     pending: null
     hospitalizedCurrently: 42
     hospitalizedCumulative: 36...
  1: 
     date: "2/25/20",
     positive: 329
     negative: 10790
     pending: null
     hospitalizedCurrently: 42
     hospitalizedCumulative: 36...
```

Comment: Can you specify in details what you want to retrieve? What is obj1, obj2?

Comment: @Tajniak updated the question with the exact expected result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might be the code you are looking for:

```
const formatted = Object.assign({},result.map(area => {
  return {
    "state": area["state"],
    "lat": area["lat"],
    "long": area["long"],
    "datasets": Object.assign({},Object.keys(area)
    .map(date => ({ date: area[date], negative: area[date]})))
  };
}))
```

Comment: bingo! Thank you

Comment: No problem,i'm glad to help :)

Comment: just a quick one, how do we add slahes to this date?  `"date": 20200421` Looking for exactly this formatting `date: "4/21/20",`

Comment: @rob.m

date = (date.slice(4)+date.slice(0,2)).match(/.{1,2}/g).join("/")

Probably not the best way but works fine

Comment: if 20200421 isnt already string first add date = date.toString()

Comment: I'm getting all dates, I'm doing something to convert but it's wrong I guess, I need to get all those dates as per the format on my comment

Comment: `var formatL = moment.localeData().longDateFormat('l');
                        var formatYearlessL = formatL.replace(/YYYY/g,'YY');
                        obj.date = moment(obj.date).format(formatYearlessL);`

Comment: how would we convert the date on your code before we build the group?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212281/discussion-between-rob-m-and-ufuk).